# I have multiple installed versions of the same haskell/cabal package. Which one is put into use?

Tags: haskell, package, ghc, cabal, ghci

Main question: I have multiple versions of a package installed. How can I know which version is being put into use when compiling or running, in ghc/ghci, a module having a module in the package as a dependency?

Related question: If I'm installing a cabal package with a dependency that can be satisfied by multiple versions of a package. Which version will be used? The latest version?

Comment: Ah. Now I understand how to use '-v' and what it means (verbose).. Not version or anything like that. I keep seeing that suggestion popping up. Now I understand it. 

With it I get information on what version is hidden in favor of the later version:
'hiding package gloss-1.6.1.1 to avoid conflict with later version gloss-1.7.0.1'
I guess that solves it then.

Answer (score 6):

ghc prefers to link with the most recent version (i.e. with the highest version number).

If linking with cabal, it will resolve versions as specified in the .cabal file (preferring newer versions when no upper bound is given).

cabal-install will prefer the newest version, unless a constraint is given.

In the presence of constraints dependency [resolution becomes NP-complete](http://people.debian.org/~dburrows/model.pdf), and cabal relies on a solver to find a satisfying package assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Some useful commands to actually see the packages that are installed and to control if they are used:

`ghc-pkg list`

`ghc-pkg register`

`ghc-pkg unregister`